# Sharing Excel file containing Power Queries without also needing the other datasource workbooks

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have an Excel file that contains a few Power Queries from other local workbooks.

Is it possible to save the file in a way to include the actual data of the queries where my users wouldn't need to have the other local workbooks for it to work? Essentially, creating a snapshot in time?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean raw data, it's not possible - Power Query queries don't keep external data. But, of course, you may save results of queries in various forms (flat tables, pivot tables, data model).

Comment: Are you referring to being to Load to table + data model?

Comment: Yes, I mean these two options + pivot table with connection directly to the query +  flat table, received from data model. But anyway it's output of the query, not input.